# Fatal error after Magento upgrade: "Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found..."

Tags: php, sql, magento

I just updated my Magento installation from 1.7 to the latest version via FTP, but now when I try to access the website or the backend I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 29298

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Shortened the title to clarify the actual *problem*, and blockquoted the error message to emphasise it in-question; as long as the error message is complete in the question *body* there's no real need to quote it in its entirety in the title, which should contain just enough information to indicate *what* the problem is, sufficient to attract attention without bogging them down in the technical data (they'll be seeing it all anyway if and when they choose to read the entire post).

Answer (score 1):

always check after remove [magento]/var folder to remove cache.

I think some core files not updated so it is giving error.

first install magento latest version then copy your modules and theme in that folders.

also check your php version should be >= 5.3.0 and give 777 permission to your magento folder.

Comment: Thanks. Website is up and running but now I can't access System > Configuration. I get the following error. 

 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Googlecheckout_Helper_Data' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: delete all files except config.xml from the following >directory: magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc/   then refresh cache and check it

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by giving the right permissions for the Mysql.php file

chmod 775 lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

I hope it helps someone else.